# Can't send email using Gmail with OAuth2

Tags: php, email, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, phpmailer

I'm trying to use OAuth2 to send emails via Gmail.

I've done all the steps described here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2

The only difference is that by default **get_oauth_token.php** requests offline access, and in the guide they don't say anything about changing this, but on screenshot it requests "*View and manage your mail*" rather then "*Offline access*". But ok, I'm authorising an app that will send emails in future without a permission prompt, so I think "offline" is exactly what I need.

But the problem is, when I use all gained credentials to send an email, it fails. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';

$email = 'hello@otdelkalux.ru';
$clientId = '407883698840-47e4rhg839eh8fm3qsfuva8b46acnl36.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$clientSecret = 'xr1Q08dGYjpSFLrwWB7laBb3';
$refreshToken = '1/JRTle_utTpfG4Mz_Z1fQiCf-qrNXzkS2PDg4iaqSHa4';

//Create a new OAuth2 provider instance
$provider = new Google([
    'clientId' => $clientId,
    'clientSecret' => $clientSecret
]);

//Pass the OAuth provider instance to PHPMailer
$mail->setOAuth(
    new OAuth([
        'provider' => $provider,
        'clientId' => $clientId,
        'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
        'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
        'userName' => $email
    ])
);

$mail->addAddress('mike.shestakov@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);                               // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Here is what server responds:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP q13sm3464715lfi.21 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO otdelkalux.ru
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [87.242.64.154]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO otdelkalux.ru
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [87.242.64.154]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1oZWxsb0BvdGRlbGthbHV4LnJ1AWF1dGg9QmVhcmVyIHlhMjkuLnpnSThvZ3pGMzRsQ01Fc2pUWjJTblRWb2FOR3lncXoxM0twMUNzaTNCLVJRd21IaWVMRzhFUVVQdExXZVY2cW1yekUBAQ==
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 q13sm3464715lfi.21 - gsmtp
SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 q13sm3464715lfi.21 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

It says username and password not accepted; however, I'm not using any password.

What am I missing? Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:** I've tried 6.0 branch, but it fails with exactly the same result. I've replaced code sample and log with a new one (above). Real credentials are in the code, so if you @synchro can reproduce this problem and help solving it, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'd recommend checking out the forthcoming [PHPMailer 6.0](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/6.0). It's working pretty well and the OAuth system has been completely rebuilt. I should be releasing it within the next week, so the more people test it the better! In other news, OAuth is still horrible to work with :)

Comment: You may have noticed that the Gmail OAuth guide isn't quite up to date - Gmail changed the way it works, but overall the steps are mostly the same. One important thing is that you must use the same email address that you use to log into gmail in the oauth properties, even if that's not the address you're sending from; the symptom you're seeing happens if you don't do that.

Comment: I've tried 6.0 with no luck. Log is still pretty much the same. I've used hello@otdelkalux.ru in google's developer console (not @gmail.com), maybe phpmailer doesn't handle this case correctly? (just guessing)

Comment: Google uses a single auth system across all their services, so that should make no difference. I'll go through it again tomorrow and update the guide.